# Run function/effect once then stop

Tags: jquery, effect

I am trying to find a way using jquery without cookies to display a block and click it to `hide()` and not show again.

It is a temporary under construction `div` on my page.

Is there any way to click it to close, which is easy enough using jQuery, then not have it load again? For it won't on the other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `div` with a conditional check of a bool variable. So in pseudocode:

```
var HasBeenViewed = false;

If (!HasBeenViewed)
{
  show div;
  HasBeenViewed = true; 
}
```

**Edit:** for it not to work on other pages you would need to use a cookie or some sort of state persistence somewhere, either on the client or the server.